# Mercurial archive specific folder/files?

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial

In SVN, I can do this to only export contents in folder2

```
svn export svn://source/Trunk/folder1/folder2 -r HEAD
```

How can I do the same in Mercurial? It seems that `hg archive` only accepts the target path not the source path. If I do `hg archive target_path/folder` it will export everything in the repository.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `--include` and `--exclude` directives

```
hg archive -I 'target_path/folder/*' my_stuff.tar
```

will get everything from `folder` on down.

Comment: thanks for your reply. However, no matter what patterns I put in, it doesn't export anything. Similarly, no matter what I put in for -X directive, it always export everything. Any ideas?

Comment: For me, it works without spaces between -I and the include pattern